# How does giving "ready to accept" signal from destination fixes the problem of "destination can't know source has placed data on data bus"

Tags: digital-logic

I am learning about destination initiated handshaking.

I will provide some context here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My confusion-:**

Problem in destination initiated strobe control was that destination had no way of knowing whether source placed data on data bus.

To fix that problem, we got "ready for data" from destination. But how does that actually solve our problem? How does destination knows whether source placed data on data bus by sending "ready for data" to source? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: gaznol - Thanks for adding more details about where you are confused. That should help site members to focus their answers so they address that specific point. I will re-open the question (@All - please write answers, as *answers*. Thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's dissect the whole procedure ("handshake") in single steps:

1. Initially all signals are not active, the systems are idle.
2. The destination signals its readiness to receive data by activating "ready for data".
3. Then it waits for the source's "data valid" to activate.
4. The source places the data on the bus.
5. Only then it activates "data valid". **This solves the problem for the destination to know when the source has placed the data on the bus.**
6. Then the source waits for the destination's "ready for data" to deactivate.
7. Because of the active "data valid", the destination is now sure, that data is available.
8. The destination reads the data.
9. Only then it deactivates "ready for data". **This solves the problem for the source to know when the destination has received the data.**
10. Then the destination waits for the source's "data valid" to deactivate.
11. Because of the inactive "ready for data", the source is now sure that the destination has read the data.
12. The source deactivates "data valid".
13. Now we have again the idle state.

*Note: I used the term "active" because control signals may come normal or inverted. Using "high" and "low" or "1" and "0", respectively, can be misleading.*

**EDIT**

> Can you tell my point number 10? Why does destination has to wait for data valid to deactivate when it has already ended receiving data(deactivates ready for data)?

At some point in its control flow the destination has to wait for "data valid" to deactivate. This is necessary before it can activate its "ready for data" again, to make sure that the source has taken notice that the destination has finished receiving.

If the destination does not wait for an inactive "data valid" and activates "ready for data" again before the source has even noticed that "ready for data" was inactive (other processing hindered it to look at the signal), the source cannot know that the destination has finished receiving.

> Should not source first deactivate data valid then destination deactivate "ready for data"?

The source cannot know by any other means that the destination has received the data, so it needs to wait for a signal from the destination. This signal is the deactivation of "ready for data". The data needs to be valid all this time, and so "data valid".

If the source deactivates "data valid" before the destination has even noticed that it was active (other processing hindered it to look at the signal), the destination cannot know that data were placed on the bus.

**Try to play this with some mate.** One of you is the source, the other the destination. You cannot see or hear each other. You have only switches (driver of signals) and lamps controlled by the switches (receiver of signals). Consider that each step takes some indetermined amount of time, including being away to get a new cup of tea (processing time).

Comment: brilliant answer, i didn't get it when i read it first, but now i read it twice or thrice and i got it.

Comment: 1 question Can you tell my point number 10? Why does destination has to wait for data valid to deactivate when it has already ended receiving data(deactivates ready for data)?Should not source first deactivate data valid then destination deactivate "ready for data"? I am confused.

Comment: >The source cannot know by any other means that the destination has received the data, so it needs to wait for a signal from the destination.

But in source initiated handshaking we first disable data valid then disable data accepted https://cvbl.iiita.ac.in/sks/coa-files/lectures/Lec_11_IO[1].pdf 15/21

Comment: This is another case, you are asking about "destination intiated handshake". In "source intiated handshake", the signal "data accepted" takes the role of "ready for data", but with inverted meaning. You can look at "data accepted" as "not ready for data". By an inactive "data accepted", the destination signals that it is "ready for data" generally.

Answer (score 1):

The AXI protocol has a READY (receiver-to-sender) and VALID (sender-to-receiver) handshake that does exactly this. Specifically, a receiver can pre-emptively 'ask' for data by raising its READY flag, even if the sender doesn't yet have data prepared. The sender 'replies' with data and asserts VALID.

What's shown is an 'interlocking' handshake. It moves through multiple states to transfer an item. While it accomplishes the task, it wastes extra cycles in the process.

AXI improves on this. In AXI, there's no restriction on when READY and VALID can be asserted or negated. Instead, the rule for AXI transfer completion is that *both* READY and VALID are asserted. They have to 'agree' that there's data there (VALID), and that it's going to be clocked in on the next cycle (READY). Once that condition is satisfied, the receiver accepts the data, and the sender is free to place the next data on the bus (VALID stays high) or not (VALID goes low).

More here: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102202/0200/Channel-transfers-and-transactions

For a destination-driven handshake as described, the AXI sender doesn't have to have data prepared immediately. It can see the READY assertion, go get the data and place it on the bus with VALID. Then and *only then* is the transfer considered complete.

The sender can also *preemptively* place data on the bus with VALID (with a FIFO, say) before READY is high, but it won't be accepted until the receiver raises READY.

Obviously, this AXI READY-VALID handshake is more efficient if more than one transfer can be done at a time. AXI is perfectly capable of doing that if both ends can keep up by holding their respective flags high, as they would for a burst transfer.

This type of handshake isn't limited to AXI, but AXI is the most likely place you will encounter it, and so it's worth your time to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
The "ready for data" informs the source about when to place the data. i.e, the destination is not currently too busy to take input (e.g, previous input has been processed).
The "data valid" informs the destination that the data is ready to be used.

Comment: you said "ready for data" informs the source about when to place the data ie destination is ready for data. why can't it be done in non handshake method ie destination initiated strobe control. we can assume when destination gives strobe, it means destination is ready to accept the data. can't we?? why?

Comment: Yes. A destination initiated strobe would be sufficient if: ((The source WILL respond within a given time limit) OR (There is a "data frame" method of detecting that data has been sent)) AND (the source always has some data to send or has a way to send NULL). In practice, SRAM "outputEnable" signal works this way. For eg: See page 9 of http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/s2004/LECTURES/l7.pdf In the SRAM case, the SRAM promises to put the data within the time constraint. If the source cannot promise that, you need a "data valid" signal.